# Setting parent variable from child class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, dependency-injection

I have a parent class `A` and a child class `B`. My goal now is to initialize `content` (property of `A`). Only `B` knows the value that should go inside `A::content`.

```
class A
{
    protected $m;
    protected $n;
    protected $p;
    protected $content;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
        $b = new B;
        $this->content = $b->getContent();
    }

    private function init() {
        $this->m = 'Nobody';
        $this->n = 'is';
        $this->p = 'like';
    }

    public function getContent() {
        return $this->content;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected $x;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
        $this->content = $this->m.' '.$this->n.' '.$this->p.' '.$this->x.' (according to '.$this->x.')';
    }

    private function init() {
        $this->x = 'Donald Trump';
    }
}

$a = new A;
echo $a->getContent();
```

In my project I have some classes - let's say B,C,D (they look like `B` in the code above). They all have one thing in common: They need the variables and methods of `A` to set the value for `A::content`.

My question now is: Is this a "good" way to achive the goal? An alternative option could be not to use inheritance but to inject an instance of `A` into the constructor of `B`... or maybe other alternatives?

EDIT:
Okay... looks like I was not able to make myself clear. Unfortunately my english is not good enough to make my point clearer.
I'm new to OOP and I'm not trying to realize all S.O.L.I.D. principles. What I'm trying is to understand
 1. where am I?
 2. where do I want to get?
 3. how can OOP helf me to get there?

EDIT:
in my real project I'm instantiating the parent (last two lines of my code). And the parent decides (by parsing $_GET) which child to instantiate : B, C or D

I solved the problem by changing the constructor of `B`... thanks to @A.P.'s hint

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::init();
    $this->init();
    $this->content = $this->m.' '.$this->n.' '.$this->p.' '.$this->x.' (according to '.$this->x.')';
}
```

Comment: A (the parent) should not know about B (the child). You are reversing the relationship. A is independent and doesn't need the child classes. B is dependent and needs the parent class. In your design, the child is independent and the parent is dependent.

Comment: I believe you should look into abstract classes so you can define the same method for all your classes, have you already explored this way?

Comment: You shouldn't rather use new in contructor, because it's hidden dependency. But I'm not sure what you want to accomplish here. Can you alter the code of A and B as you want? For example change visibility of init() method to public/protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow are my corrections to make what you are trying to do work. However you cannot create a A class and expect it to get the data from the B class (which is a child)
But you can access the constructor of the A class from the B class

```
    class A
{
    protected $m;
    protected $n;
    protected $p;
    protected $content;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }

    private function init() {
        $this->m = 'Nobody';
        $this->n = 'is';
        $this->p = 'like';
    }

    public function getContent() {
        return $this->content;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected $x;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->init();
        $this->content = $this->m.' '.$this->n.' '.$this->p.' '.$this->x.' (according to '.$this->x.')';
    }

    private function init() {

        $this->x = 'Donald Trump';
    }

     public function getContent() {
        return $this->content;
    }
}

$B = new B;
echo $B->getContent();
```

Comment: your example works... and using the parent constructor is a good hint. Thnx. What I didn't mention: in my real project I'm instantiating A. And A decides (by parsing $_GET) which child to instantiate : B, C or D. I can not instantiate B (last two lines of your code) because I don't know wheather its B or C or D I will need.

Comment: "you cannot create a A class and expect it to get the data from the B class" - I can and I will ;-)